# "Archive" tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Does SQL Server 2005/2008 have something similar to MySQL Archive table?

What we need: no updating, no deleting, no locking, no transaction for specific table(s), only insert and select.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to turn off logging and transactions in SQL Server.

Comment: Nothing built in, but you could simulate some of those features.

Comment: Typically, you use security to prevent updates and deletes, although you could define some no-op update/delete triggers, I suppose.  There's no way to disable locking or transactions in the SQL Server sense of those terms.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not have an Archive feature, but as mentioned, you can mimic one.

You can "trick" SQL Server to not do anything you would normally do with a table, by using `triggers` in a special way.

Use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.

It requires a bit more work (namely a repeated UPDATE statement) but any time you can prevent work, instead of letting it happen and then rolling it back, or do something else.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Item_BeforeUpdate_AnyBilled]
ON [dbo].[Item]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  ... my code to avoid UPDATE here
END
GO
```